# Push notification alert not displaying when coming out of background

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

Ive got the following code in my app delegate to display the text contained in a Push notification within a UIAlertView.

The code works fine while the app is still loaded in the background, however, once the app goes out of the background, the notification doesn't appear.

Can somebody much cleverer than me show me where I am going wrong, and what I need to do to fix it?

app Delegate.m:

```
@synthesize pushText;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [Parse setApplicationId:@"hGG5RdgNVdI7eCeZynV32lWYXywQRHkpp5zLdY7Q"
                  clientKey:@"TwmNbpBYEt4u3euE3lzNIgwyroSl8RPGF2dJFsPv"];

    // Register for Push Notitications, if running iOS 8
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
        UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                        UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                        UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                                 categories:nil];
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
    } else {
        // Register for Push Notifications before iOS 8
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                         UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                         UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
    }
    return YES;

    NSMutableArray *alertTextArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"alertTextArray"];
    NSDictionary *notifKey = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

    if (notifKey)
    {
        [alertTextArray addObject:[notifKey objectForKey:@"alert"]];

    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:alertTextArray forKey:@"alertTextArray"];







}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.

    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    if (currentInstallation.badge != 0) {
        currentInstallation.badge = 0;
        [currentInstallation saveEventually];
    }
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    // Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
    pushText = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"News", "")
                                                    message:pushText
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];




}


@end
```

Comment: Notifications won't show up on lock screen when app is in foreground. Show them in alert and follow the manual from Parse.

Comment: not exactly what i meant. When the app is fully closed, and a push notification comes in, the above code does not display the UIAlert like it should. However, when the app is in the background (i.e. not being currently used, but has been opened) the UIAlert does appear.

Comment: You get dictionary with push info when app restarts, it's in launch options, check docs.

Comment: Thank you! thats what i was missing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get dictionary with push info when app restarts, it's in launch options, check docs.

ps: Copying my comment as answer

Comment: Thanks. and thanks for replying - its nice to find people who are willing to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean that when the app is in Foreground (= Running), notifications alert does not show ?

This is actually by design and how iOS notifications work.
If the app is running, notifications alert are not shown and it is up to your app to display them in a way that is meaningful for your application.

Comment: No, the app is not running. When the notification comes in, the above code works fine. but when the app is not open at all, the notification is not displayed in the alert view like it should be.

Comment: Did you check the notification center preference for that application ? What is the configuration ? When the app is not running if correctly configured, it should display a standard iOS notification (as configured in you notification center), but not display your UIAlert. If your app is not in foreground, it does not have the right to display anything on screen.